# npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '..."jscs":"~3.0.7","moch'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I have a problem with npm. I tried: `npx create-react-app my-app` but it returned an error.

My command prompt output:

```
c:\Users\sysli\Desktop\reactprojects>npx create-react-app my-app
npx: installed 91 in 34.825s

Creating a new React app in c:\Users\sysli\Desktop\reactprojects\my-app.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '..."jscs":"~3.0.7","moch'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\sysli\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-12-26T21_21_02_198Z-debug.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting my-app/ from c:\Users\sysli\Desktop\reactprojects
Done.
```

Log file:
https://justpaste.it/3s5ym

Comment: "moch' <-- is that a single quote?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update npm on your machine (*Prasool advice*):

```
sudo npm i -g npm
```

If it does not work as expected, please use

```
npm cache clean --force
```

as it seems to work for some around here and GitHub. :)

Have a happy coding time!

Answer (score 0):

Can you retry after updating npm?

npm install -g npm

Please note that this command will remove your current version of npm. Make sure to use 
sudo npm install -g npm if on a Mac.